# Contrapositive of Statement

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

What is the contrapositive of the following statement.

$A∩B^c=∅$ if $A⊆B$.

$B^c$ means $B$ complement

Comment: What have you attempted? Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

If $A \cap B^c\neq\varnothing$, then $A\not\subseteq B$.